# i'm not getting result with jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

this is HTML code and below is the jquery code..my problem is in jquery code as i have 4 `if` statments and 1 `else` statment...my code is going into first two `if` statement and then it is skipping the next two `if`statements and directly goes into the last `else` statement..i have check this by `alert` function in each `if`statement and i got `alert` from first two statements and then from the last `else`statement...can somebody tell the solution??? also please tell me how can i get the errors of all when i call `$("#errors").html(errormsg);` as i wrote this to get errors if any but it doesn't show anything on screen please give reply of both questions thanks.

```
<head>
<style>
#container{
width:500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#errors{
color:red;
margin-left:200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="errors"></div>
<div id="container">
    <form id="validationform">

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email"/>

        <label for="phone">Telephone</label>
        <input name="phone" id="phone"/>

        <label for="pass">Password</label>
        <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass"/>

        <label for="cpass">Confirm Password</label>
        <input name="cpass" type="password" id="cpass"/>
        <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

<script>
var errormsg = "";
$("#validationform").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Regular expression started
    function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };

    if (!isValidEmailAddress($("#email").val())) {
        alert("in emails if");
        errormsg = "please enter a valid email address";

    }
    if (!$.isNumeric($("#phone").val())) {
        alert("in phone if");
        errormsg += "<br>" + "Please enter a numeric phone number";
    }

    if ($("#pass").val() != $("#cpass").val()) {
        alert("in pass if");
        errormsg += "<br>" + "both passwords do not match";
    }

    if (errormsg = "") {
        alert("now in success if");
        alert("success");
    }
    else {
        alert("in last errors if");
        $("#errors").html(errormsg);
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: There is input type="emal" that validates the email -- and for phone type="number"  -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: ya but thats not a problem main problem is of jquery code as the code is not really traversing all the if and else statements...how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working exactly as you coded it to work.
However you have some small mistakes.
`if (errormsg = "")` should be `if (errormsg == "")`. Single `=` is for assigning not comparing.
The code is skipping the next if statement because you entered the same passwords in the fields.
 If you enter different passwords the if statement will execute.
The other if statement is skipping because you are assigning empty string to `errormsg` (you are using single `=`) and that returns the same value `""` empty string, which is than passed to the if statement, and because `""` is not a number, the if statement evaluates to false and the if statement it is not executed.

Comment: thanks a lot dear my problem is now sloved and thanks for explaining in details. @wazaaaap